# Grouping Data in React Native FlatList

Tags: reactjs, flatlist

My data is like this:

```
[
  [
    'id' => 1,
    'date' => '2021-04-19',
    'name' => 'John Doe',
    'payment' => 25
  ],
  [
    'id' => 2,
    'date' => '2021-04-19',
    'name' => 'Mary Doe',
    'payment' => 23
  ],
  [
    'id' => 3,
    'date' => '2021-04-18',
    'name' => 'Peter Pan',
    'payment' => 30
  ],
  [
    'id' => 4,
    'date' => '2021-04-18',
    'name' => 'Mike Myers',
    'payment' => 18
  ],
  [
    'id' => 5,
    'date' => '2021-04-17',
    'name' => 'Jack Cole',
    'payment' => 28
  ]
]
```

I want an output like this:

```
2021-04-19
---------------------
| John Doe - 25     |
---------------------
| Mary Doe - 23     |
---------------------

2021-04-18
---------------------
| Peter Pan - 30    |
---------------------
| Mike Myers - 18   |
---------------------

2021-04-17
---------------------
| Jack Cole - 28    |
---------------------
```

In my render method I have this:

```
return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <FlatList
      data={myjsondata}
      keyExtractor={(item: any) => item.id}
      renderItem={this._renderList}
      showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
    />
  </View>
);
```

My `_renderList` function is like this:

```
  _renderList = ({item}:any) => {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>{item.date}</Text>
        <TouchableOpacity>
          <View>
            <Text>
              {item.name}
            </Text>
            <Text>
              ${item.payment}
            </Text>
          </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  };
```

I have tried using state but apparently it cannot be used inside the renderList loop. Can this be achieved through Flatlist, or should I use SectionList instead? Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

You can modify your render method to roughly this:

```
const groupedData = Object.values(myjsondata.reduce((spd, item) => {
  if (!spd[item.date]) spd[item.date] = {
      name: item.date,
      items: []
  };
  spd[item.date].items.push(item);
  return spd;
}, {}));
//as we have grouped data we then shows it
       return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={{ flex: 1, marginTop: 20 }} >
          {
              groupedData.map(group => (
                  <View>
                      <Text style={{marginLeft: 20}}>{group.name}</Text>
                      <FlatList
          data={group.items}
          keyExtractor={(item: any) => item.id}
          renderItem={this._renderList}
          showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
        />
                  </View>
              ))
          }
      </View>
      </View>
    );
```

Answer (score -1):

**Array.map should never be used in rendering in React Native. Always prefer a FlatList or some other virtualized list implementation.**

**In this case `<SectionList/>` is what you're looking for.**

https://reactnative.dev/docs/sectionlist

```js
// You should transform your Data to the following shape ->
const DATA = [{
    title: '2021-04-19',
    data: [{name: "Mary Doe", payment: 20},{name: "John Doe", payment: 30}],
  },
  {
    title: '2021-04-18',
    data: [{name: "James Doe", payment: 70}],
  }
];
```

**Use Functional components, extract `renderItem` and `renderSectionHeader` into functions, and wrap them in a `useCallback`**

Example:

```js
import { View, Text, SectionList } from 'react-native';

const keyExtractor = (item: any) => `${item.id}`;

const sectionListHeader = (title: string) => (
  <View>
    <Text>{title}</Text>
  </View>
);

const handleRenderSectionHeader = ({
  section: { title },
}: {
  section: SectionListData<
    DATA,
    {
      title: string;
      data: any[];
    }
  >;
}) => sectionListHeader(title);

const renderItem: ListRenderItem<DATA> = ({ item }) => (
  <ListItemComponent data={item} />
);

const Screen = () => {
  return (
    <SectionList
      sections={data}
      keyExtractor={keyExtractor}
      renderItem={renderItem}
      renderSectionHeader={handleRenderSectionHeader}
      stickySectionHeadersEnabled={false}
      ItemSeparatorComponent={spacingBetweenItems}
      refreshControl={
        <RefreshControl refreshing={loading} onRefresh={refetch} />
      }
      ListFooterComponent={sectionListFooter}
    />
  );
};

export { Screen };
```